# Changed root password on Mac and cannot access phpMyAdmin using XAMPP localhost

Tags: phpmyadmin

So, I changed my root password for my mysql database using a localhost on XAMPP, and am unable to access phpMyAdmin entirely.

Sifting through resources online, I've find nearly no solution and am seriously confused as to what to do to remedy this. It seems like my primary dilemma is adding my root password to my /phpmyadmin/config.inc.php file. For some reason, I'm unable to do this as I'm not permitted to edit this file?

When trying to change my username from Daemon to my own (from within /etc/httpdconf), it seems to mess up the program even more by not allowing me to launch apache at all.

I'm not sure how to go about this. XAMPPS files seem to be in some directory that I cannot reach from the terminal, called LAMPP.

Any input as to how I can fix this would be much appreciated![enter image description here][1]

running osx sierra 10.12.4

Comment: Normally you do not have to add your root password to phpMyAdmin's config.inc.php, if you are using the 'cookie' auth_type, which shows you a login panel for phpMyAdmin. Do you see this login panel?

Comment: No, I don't. This is what pops up when trying to run phpmyadmin using my local host.

Error MySQL said: Documentation

#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

 phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Comment: Well you need to find out why you cannot edit phpMyAdmin's config.inc.php. With which OSX user are you trying to edit?